# Laravel 7.0 project run Without PHP artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have issue in this.,
I change server.php in root folder to index.php and .htaccess file in public folder move to root folder But even though i am getting **This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500**

Comment: Its the permission problem

Comment: Check your server php version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this Problem like Changing PHP Version..
Because the Laravel 7.0 requires PHP version 7.2 Or Above but i am Running the Laravel 7.0 Application in 7.1 that's why it showiing like this..After Changing PHP  version to 7.4 it fixed.....

Answer (score 0):

In a laravel application your web server should have as base the public folder.

server.php is not the entrypoint but a file for use php artisan serve when you develop with internal server of PHP.

In order to have more information about the error set APP_DEBUG=true in your .env file